# How to create a connection string using C# to SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have a database for user details in my SQL Server and I have already written a C# login application. I need to connect this application to my database to get user data. Before that, I think I should connect my database to Visual Studio using a connection string.

Can anyone please tell me a way of creating a connection string to connect my database to the application?

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171886(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: How did you write a login application without ever connecting it to a database?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `app.config` file just add it by right click your project > add > new item > search box type application then select `Application Configuration File` then click `Add` button below. then open the `App.config` file and `paste` the code below.

It will be has a name of `App.config` in your project.

```
<configuration>
       <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
     <add name="conn" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=YourDBName;user=YourUsername;password=YourPassword; default command timeout=120;;" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

See this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149592/how-to-add-key-value-from-web-config-file-to-database-by-uploading-excel-sheet?noredirect=1#comment75318591_44149592)  to run the code.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can use EntityFramework [database first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx) convention. The easiest way is to add **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** from visual studio Project -> Add New Item -> Data and then wizard helps you to connect to your database and creates required objects for tables in code